# Parse a JSON structure with symbol instead of a string for an attribute

Tags: java, json, rest

I am working on an HTTP Rest query.
Wikipedia API returns a JSON. The problem is the JSON structure returned by Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=pizza

This is the JSON obtained via a rest request to the Wikipedia API. To view the full JSON, you can click on the above link.

```
{
  "parse":
  {
    "title":"Pizza",
    "pageid":24768,
    "text":{"*":"<div class=\...>"}
  }
}
```

I would parse this using a custom deserializer which I haven't got a chance to test. Trying to parse with simple Gson like the following return null;

```
Result res   = new Gson(str,Result.class);
```

I have created the classes like the following:

```
public class Result
{
  private Parse parse;
}

public class Parse 
{
  private String title;
  private int pageid;
  private Text text;
}

public class Text{

 private String *;// what should I call this attribute.

}
```

My plan is to add a custom deserializer like the following:

```
public class TextBaseDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Text> {

    @Override
    public RespondentBase deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        return jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(jsonElement.get("*"),Text.class);
    }

  
}
```

I am using Gson to parse this, like the following:

```
Gson tmp = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Text.class, new TextBaseDeserializer());
// let's assume that str is the string obtained following Rest based request from Java.
Result res = tmp.parse(str,Result.class);
```

I have done all the above code to handle the symbolic JSON attribute.
My question is how to parse such a JSON. In the above example, the attribute is a *

Comment: personally, i would annotate field in model, so in gson which you are using it would be something like `@SerializedName("*")`

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. It was during an online test. I tried this on localIDE it works syntactically.

Comment: `new new GsonBuilder()` ?? Please never type code into StackOverflow's editor -- ALWAYS copy/paste to avoid typos.  How do we know the code in your post doesn't have other errors?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65985688/parse-a-json-structure-with-symbol-instead-of-a-string-for-an-attribute/65987066#comment116666176_65985688), you should annotated field with `@SerializedName("*")`.

You can name the field whatever you want. We'll just name it `star` below, but maybe `all` is better, since `*` might be a wildchar? Doesn't really matter, just choose whatever name you like.

```java
class Text
{
    @SerializedName("*")
    private String star;
}
```

*Test*

```java
String str = "{\"parse\":{\"title\":\"Pizza\",\"pageid\":24768,\"text\":{\"*\":\"<div class=\\\"mw-parser-output\\\">...</div>\"}}}";

Gson tmp = new GsonBuilder().create();
Result res = tmp.fromJson(str, Result.class);
System.out.println(res.getParse().getText().getStar());
```

*Output*

```html
<div class="mw-parser-output">...</div>
```